# Best method of implementing Picasso.Builder and onImageLoadFailed function

Tags: java, android, listener, picasso

For the past few days I have been implementing Picasso in my Android project. Initial implementation was easy enough, but now I have run into an issue I cannot seem to resolve and have not found a clear answer to in either the Picasso documentation or other tuturials/stackoverflow questions.
My knowledge of java is sufficient, but Android and more advanced OOP concepts are quite new to me so please bear this in mind.

Initially I implemented Picasso like this in my RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.image.getContext()).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.image.getContext())
            .load(new File("imagePath"))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(viewHolder.image);
}
```

This worked fine, but due to unrelated errors I wished to implement debugging options and looked towards the onError() and onImageLoadFailed() functions. Resulting in the following implementation:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(viewHolder.image.getContext());
    builder.indicatorsEnabled(true);
    builder.loggingEnabled(true);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", " onImageLoadFailed message");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    builder.build().load(new File("imagePath"))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(viewHolder.image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                 @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d("TAG", " onError message");
                }
            });
```

However, with this implementation Picasso seemed to never reload images from memory when I scrolled through my Recyclerviewer. Therefore I tried the following:

```
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(viewHolder.image.getContext()).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", " onImageLoadFailed message");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).build();

    picasso.with(viewHolder.image.getContext())
            .setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    picasso.with(viewHolder.image.getContext())
            .load(new File("imagePath"))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(viewHolder.image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d("TAG", " onError message");
                }
            });
```

This implementation seems to work nicely (although it does seem that some images are loaded in memory much quicker than others, perhaps due to .fit(), my next objective will be to optimize file loading speed).

However I am uncertain if this is the best implementation. I have tried to find the answer in the Picasso documentation and it seems to be related to the creation of new Picasso instances / Picasso being a singelton. However, I am afraid I am too inexperienced to fully understand this and there seem to be no tutorials on this topic.

So my main question is as follows: What is the best way of implementing Picasso in a project/throughout multiple activities? Should I use  Picasso.Builder to access the onImageLoadFailed function? And if so, should I use it for every activity or not?

Thank you in advance for your help!